# ng-repeat как элемент не работает для таблиц

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-repeat

На официальном сайте [документации](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) есть ссылка на пример работы директивы и там же описание использования её как элемента.
Немного поколдовав я попытался сделать пример работы директивы как элемента. Что не так?

https://plnkr.co/edit/iAyyhrS3dOiwy6BY5U9O?p=preview

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate']).controller('repeatController', function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Joy', age:15, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Mary', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Peter', age:95, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Sebastian', age:50, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Erika', age:27, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Patrick', age:40, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Samantha', age:60, gender:'girl'}
  ];
});
})(window.angular);

/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngRepeat-production</title>
  <link href="animations.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-animate.js"></script>

  
</head>
<body ng-app="ngRepeat">
  <div ng-controller="repeatController">
  I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
  <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter friends..." aria-label="filter friends" />

  <br><br>
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results" colspan=2><span ng-bind="friend.name"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <ng-repeat ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </ng-repeat>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/bQ8fr8tgFNEjyz7aaoQZ?p=preview

Comment: уже несколько вопросов было по этой теме: это такое поведение браузера для элементов, которые не могут находиться в данном контейнере

Comment: и если посмотришь разметку итоговую увидишь, что элемент ng-repeat отработал, просто был вынесен за таблицу

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, всё таки придётся костыль делать в виде диррективы ...

Comment: эм, вообще-то нет, ng-repeat прекрасно работает в виде атрибута, а не элемента, если ты хотел повторять сразу несколько td, то просто посмотри на ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end

Comment: @Grundy, на сколько я понял работу ng-repeat-start/ng-repeat-end - там повторяется ng-repeat-start и закрывается всё ng-repeat-end. А мне нужно, что бы вёрстка (в том числе и вложенные директивы) повторялась, без лишних закрывающих элементов и повторения tr.

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh, так непонятно, что ты имеешь на входе и какую разметку в итоге хочешь получить. Можешь задать еще один вопрос, возможно либо ты не совсем понял как работает start/end, либо я не понял что тебе нужно

Comment: @Grundy, имеем <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">, но нужно что бы ng-repeat повторял только содержимое tr, без самого <tr>. Это возможно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46064/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexey-lemesh).